# VBA ADODB update recordset

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I am trying to read the contents of two different tabs in a worksheet and compare them by using ADODB and querying techniques VBA.

Below you can find my code:

```
stCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _
 & "Data Source=" & wbBook.FullName & ";" _
 & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Readonly = False"";"
' MsgBox (stCon)
'here is SQL code to gather data including our calculation from two tables within the workbook
'stSQL = "SELECT [Recon_Daily_Xml_report$].RECTYPEGLEDGER, [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE, ([Recon_Daily_Xml_report$].Amount_Abs - [GL_Activity_totals$].BILLINGAMT) as Amount_Diff ,"
'stSQL = stSQL & " ([Recon_Daily_Xml_report$].NUMOFENTRIES - [GL_Activity_totals$].NUMOFTRXNS) as Count_Diff "
'stSQL = stSQL & " FROM [Recon_Daily_Xml_report$], [GL_Activity_totals$]"
'stSQL = stSQL & " WHERE Lower([Recon_Daily_Xml_report$].RECTYPEGLEDGER) = Lower([GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE)"
'stSQL = stSQL & " ORDER BY [Recon_Daily_Xml_report$].RECTYPEGLEDGER ASC"

stSQL = "SELECT LCASE([GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE),Sum(ABS([GL_Activity_totals$].BILLINGAMT)),Sum([GL_Activity_totals$].NUMOFTRXNS) "
stSQL = stSQL & " FROM [GL_Activity_totals$] "
stSQL = stSQL & " Group By [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE "
stSQL = stSQL & " ORDER BY [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE ASC"


'MsgBox (stSQL)
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

cnt.Open stCon
'rst.Open stSQL, cnt, 1, 3
rst.Open stSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
'rst.Open strSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
With rst


    Do While Not .EOF
    If rst.Fields.Item(0).Value <> "" Then
       strString = Replace(rst.Fields.Item(0).Value, "  ", " ")

        rst.Update
        rst.Fields.Item(0) = strString

    End If
    .MoveNext
    Loop

End With
```

This specific code gives me back an error suggesting that I cannot update the field in the recordset I want to update when reading it. The error I am currently getting is:

```
Run-time error '-2147217911 Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.
```

Tried to change the way i open the recordset by using 1,3 option but again i was getting the same error.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with

```
LCASE([GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE)
```

and with the GROUP BY.
In this case, rst.Fields.Item(0) is an expression, not a table value. You can't update expressions. Also, since you're using GROUP BY, the recordset is not linked to any particular record for access to edit. You could accomplish the same task purely in SQL

```
cnt.Execute("UPDATE [GL_Activity_totals$] " & _
" SET [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE = Substitute([GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE,'  ', ' ') " & _
" WHERE NOT [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE IS NULL " & _
" AND [GL_Activity_totals$].TRXNTYPE <> '';")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Replace functionality in Update for ADODB VBA is not recognised. So the replace is not being done.

Comment: Do i need to make any other changes for this to work? the final outcome that i want is to replace all the extra spaces within the strings of the trxntypes that are in the recordset.

Comment: After reviewing your question again, I wonder if it would be better to just open the worksheet without using ADODB, but in any case I think Substitute should work instead of Replace since it's excel