# Cannot read Database or object read only

Tags: vba, excel, ado, jet

I am trying to query an Excel file from another file using VBA and ADO options. When I run this code it's throwing the error "Cannot updata, Database or object Read only":

```
Public Function fnExecuteXlQuery _
    (ByVal strPath As String,  _
    ByVal strQuery As String) As ADODB.Recordset

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conStr As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " _ 
      & "Data Source=" & strPath & "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strQuery, conStr, adOpenDynamic

Set fnExecuteXlQuery = rs

Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
Set fnExecuteXlQuery = Nothing
fnDisplayError Error(Err) & "Unable to fetch data from DTS...", ERROR_TYPE_ERROR
End Function
```

The "**strPath**" is the source Excel file and the "**strquery**" has the following SQL code:

```
Select [Activity],[Name],[Date],[Hours Spent] 
from [Time sheet$] 
where [Activity] = 'Billable Activities' 
Order by Name,date
```

Comment: asking the obvious - is the `strPath` spelled correctly with all folder paths and file name and such?

Comment: Yes it is.. there are no variations

Comment: I can't see any updating going on there. Where are you actually getting the error?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002805/update-an-excel-sheet-using-vba-ado  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998502/vba-adodb-update-recordset

Comment: @Rory There is no update just a select query but the error shows its read only

Comment: @Anarach Is it actually an .xls file, or a newer format? Also, you really should enclose the field names in the ORDER BY clause in  parentheses too as you're using keywords like `Date` for names.

Comment: @Rory Its .Xlsx , and yes i enlosed them in [] still not workin

Comment: @Anarach Then your connection string is wrong. You should almost certainly be using `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and not Jet4 and the extended properties should be `Excel 12 XML`. Your code shouldn't work at all unless the file is open, and it's not a good idea to query open workbooks due to memory leaks.

Comment: @Rory Well i just change it to ACE.OLEDB and i get a new error "" could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: @Anarach Just ot be sure, you did use: `conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; "`? Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Yes I am using the exact same code and excel is 2010 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all of what has been said in the comments just needs to be written out once more to make sure that you really got the solution right:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConnectionToExcel()
Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConnectin As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strSQL As String

strPath = "C:\Data\YourFile.xlsm"

strConnectin = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & strPath & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"" "
Debug.Print strConnection

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Time sheet$] "

Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
rstResult.Open strSQL, strConnectin, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rstResult

End Sub
```

Please note, that I am taking it one step at a time: (1) I am using a `sub` instead of a function. (2) The `select` has been simplified just to test the connection and can be later expanded upon. (3) Just writing back the result to the first sheet. (4) Further restricting the recordset to be `adOpenForwardOnly` only and `adLockReadOnly`.

Also, keep in mind that the above code uses early binding and thus requires you to set a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library` (or later) in `Tools` --> `References...`.